# View Fault and Update Domains of virtual machine in Azure through Python Script

Tags: python, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-sdk-python

Is there any way  i can get the update domain and fault domain of the particular vm through python script.

I don't want to use powershell commands.

<< In Power Shell we can do this >>

http://windowsitpro.com/azure/view-fault-and-update-domains-azure-resource-manager

<< /Power Shell >>

I am looking for azure python cli. which can do this task.

Comment: Do you mean azure python cli?

Comment: @Walter-MSFT yes ... I mean azure python cli.

Comment: I use python cli get vm's `update domain ` and `fault domain` successfuly, you could check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132978/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-10305059).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could use the following command

`az vm show -g yourgroup -n vmname --expand  instanceView`

You could get your VM's `platformFaultDomain` and `platformUpdateDomain`

[image]

Comment: the cli accepts a complex query to get the same output than PS: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli#querying