# Find Fault Domain for given VM/instance in Azure

Tags: azure, terraform, ansible-inventory, azure-availability-set

I have a Scale Set I provisioned in Azure through Terraform.
(A scale set is an implicit availability set with 5 fault domains and 5 update domains.[ [1]])

I need to find out which Fault Domain each instance is in, so that I can configure my application cluster based on this, for improved redundancy.

So far, I have found only a single post remotely addressing this[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41606832/view-fault-and-update-domains-of-virtual-machine-in-azure-through-python-script).

More context:

- I can switch to regular VMs rather than a scale set if there is absolutely no other way.
- I use ansible's dynamic inventory (azure_rm.py) which I have already customised to work with Scale Sets. If the solution can leverage this, extra kudos :)
- My application allows me to define topology (datacentre, rack, etc.) and I am deploying it in a single Azure datacentre. Maybe I have missed a different solution?

Many many thanks,
–Jeff

Comment: so with which tool do you want to find that out?

Comment: It would be perfect if I could find it out with the ansible dynamic-inventory. I am currently looking into the Python Azure SDK, which I think the former leverages.

Comment: Something like [this](http://windowsitpro.com/azure/view-fault-domain-all-vms-cloud-service)?

Comment: @JeroenHeier indeed, but I have to run it from a Linux machine.

Comment: @JeroenHeier I'll see on Monday if I can use the same 'field names' in the Python API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by using the 169.254.169.254 'virtual IP' that allows a VM in the could to read its own metadata.

Specifically, I am running:

```
curl -H Metadata:true --silent "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance/compute/platformFaultDomain?api-version=2017-03-01&format=text"
```

in an Ansible task, and then using Ansible's [local facts](http://serverascode.com/2015/01/27/ansible-custom-facts.html) to make this available as an Ansible variable on the host.